# Trying to raise quotas in Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine, quota

We're running a very time sensitive migration that requires a good number of VM's, but we hit our limit on the very first one and we can't continue with our configuration until this is resolved.

Resources required:

Current Use:
VM's = 1
vCPUs = 8
vRAM = 16GB
Persistent Balanced Boot Disk = 250GB

Additional Use:
VM's = 10
vCPUs = 40
vRAM = 80GB
Persistent Balanced Boot Disk = 2.5TB (250GB per VM)

Ive reached out to all the relevant teams I can and ive had nothing back

Comment: When you reach your quota limit you received a warning. Please share your warning

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is common and super easy to get raised.
Navigate to your cloud console, find the quotas page, then the quota you want to increase and then increase it. Make sure you click save!

google's documentation on the subject can be found here if you need more information: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6376374?hl=en

In most cases, you can raise the quota yourself with gce.